# Laravel Eager with Where constraint

Tags: php, laravel-blade, eager-loading, laravel-5

I have 2 methods with eager loading and paginate. but problem is that i have to use where constraint too and i am getting offset 0 error.

```
public function showAllOrders(){
    $orders = \admin\Order::with('orderfiles','paymentStatus','orderStatus','orderDelivery','flexibleDelivery')->paginate(20);
        return View('admin.all_orders')
            ->with('orders',$orders);
}

public function showAllPaidOrders(){
    $orders = \admin\Order::with(array('orderfiles','orderStatus','orderDelivery','flexibleDelivery','paymentStatus'=>function($query){
        $query->where('status', '=', 'Paid');
    }))->paginate(20);
        return View('admin.all_orders')
            ->with('orders',$orders);
}
```

showAllOrders working fine but when i am using where constraint with showAllPaidOrders i am getting offset error....

> 1/2
>       ErrorException in Collection.php line 837:
>       Undefined offset: 0
>       2/2
>       ErrorException in Collection.php line 837:
>       Undefined offset: 0 (View: E:\content\xampp\htdocs\l5\resources\views\admin\all_orders.blade.php)

Even if both blade views are same. The only difference is the "**Where Constraint**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this with using wherehas function

```
public function showAllOrdersbySite($domain_id){
    $orders = Order::whereHas('paymentStatus', function ($query) use($domain_id) {
        $query->where("domain_id","=",$domain_id);

    })->orderby('tbl_orders.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return View('admin.all_orders')
            ->with('orders',$orders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and even if you want to check multiples relation you can add whereHas again and again as per as your requirement.